# Adding List of used fabrication services to combo box through collection

Tags: revit-api

I'm having some issues getting this to work. I'm trying to get a list of used fabrication services to appear in a combobox so that can select and isolate that service to renumber anything associated with that service. Not sure if I'm heading in the right direction here. Still new to revit api.
[Error in catch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3kOyP.png)

Dubug error

System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'IsCheckboxEnabled' property not found on 'object' ''ServiceGroup' (HashCode=30800802)'. BindingExpression:Path=IsCheckboxEnabled; DataItem='ServiceGroup' (HashCode=30800802); target element is 'ServiceGroupCheckBox' (Name=''); target property is 'IsEnabled' (type 'Boolean')

```
 try
        {
            ICollection<FabricationService> fabricationService =
                (ICollection<FabricationService>)new FilteredElementCollector(Doc, Doc.ActiveView.Id).OfCategory(BuiltInCategory.OST_FabricationPipework)
                .ToElements();
            {
                foreach (FabricationService service in fabricationService)
                    comboBox2.Items.Add(service);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image you linked shows an error stating:

> Unable to cast object of type
> 'System.Collections.Generic.List'1[Autodesk.Revit.DB.Element]' to type
> 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection'1[Autodesk.Revit.DB.FabricationService]'.

You have a casting error, try casting like this:

```
using System.Linq;

IEnumerable<FabricationService> fabricationServices =
    new FilteredElementCollector(doc, doc.ActiveView.Id)
        .OfCategory(BuiltInCategory.OST_FabricationPipework)
        .Cast<FabricationService>();

foreach (FabricationService fabricationService in fabricationServices)
{
    comboBox2.Items.Add(fabricationService);
}
```

I'm guessing FabricationService objects are returned with the built in category you specified above, I don't use these in my work. You could also use a class filter instead:

```
IEnumerable<FabricationService> fabricationServices =
    new FilteredElementCollector(doc, doc.ActiveView.Id)
        .OfClass(typeof(FabricationService))
        .Cast<FabricationService>();
```

Comment: I had eventually found out that I was indeed missing the cast & forgot to come back to the post. Thanks for the answer.